# Is multiple batch files accessing/setting the same shared/global variable thread-safe?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

**fileOne.bat**

```
SET varTest=5
START fileTwo.bat
SET varTest=8
PAUSE
```

**fileTwo.bat**

```
ECHO %varTest%
```

Is multiple batch files accessing/setting the same shared/global variable "thread-safe"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. `filetwo.bat` starts with a copy of the environment from `fileone.bat`.

The two processes are however quite independent since the second file is `start`ed. They do not share an environment so the change to a variable in `fileone.bat` is not visible from `filetwo.bat`, nor is any change to `filetwo.bat`'s environment visible from `fileone.bat`.

If `filetwo.bat` is `call`ed from `fileone.bat` instead of being `start`ed, then `filetwo.bat` will need to be completed before `fileone.bat` continues. ANy changes made by `filetwo.bat` will then be visible in `fileone.bat`'s environment once `fileone.bat` resumes.

This behaviour with `call` can be stopped if you want by using `setlocal` within `filetwo.bat`. Any change made in `filetwo.bat` before the `setlocal` will be visible to `fileone.bat`, but any changes made after the `setlocal` will be backed out when `filetwo.bat` terminates or if an `endlocal` instruction is encountered (after which any changes subsequently made will be visible in `fileone.bat`)

Comment: Thank you Magoo and @mc-nd. Answer as accepted answer because of a random choice, since your two answers solved my question.

Answer (score 1):

There are two options

- Both batch files are running inside the same `cmd.exe` instance: for this to happen, one of the batch files is waiting for the other to end, so, there is not any concurrent access to the variable.
- Each batch file is running inside a different `cmd.exe` instance: each instance has its own enviornment, so, there is not any concurrent access to the variable.

That means that there is not any problem in reading/writting the same variable at the same time as this can not happen.